# <select> option closes <ul> dropdown menu

Tags: html, jquery, select, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown menu of checkboxes and some checkboxes with a `<select>` dropdown.
I have successfully used the `e.stopPropagation()` on the checkboxes.

The problem is that selecting an option in the `<select>` also closes the dropdown.  I have tried adding it to the `$(document).on('click', '.oneClass .anotherClass', function(e)` but it still closes the dropwdown.  I have tried other answers but they don't seem to apply.

This is the Code:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.allow-focus', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="preciplist" class="dropdown-menu allow-focus scrollable-menu" style="width:300px;">
  <li id="nump1box"><label><input type="checkbox" name="numprecip1box" id="numprecip1box" checked>Number of Days</label><br>
    <select id="snowliq1" name="1snowliq" style="width: min-content; color:#ffffff; background-color:#2c3e50; display:inline;" class="parameterInput form-control input-sm">
      <option value="snow">Snow</option>
      <option selected value="liq">Liquid</option>
    </select>
    <select id="NumPrecip1" name="1precipval" style="width: min-content; color:#ffffff; background-color:#2c3e50; display:inline;" class="parameterInput form-control input-sm">
      <option value="">select one</option>
    </select>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Any ideas?
Thanks Dave

Comment: A dropdown menu only stays open while you're selecting something from it. If you click anywhere else, it can't stay open.

Comment: If you want something with a different UI style, you'll need to implement it explicitly in your own HTML and JS.